# Apple Mail wrong receive date for emails after moving the emails

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, email, exchange

We used an Exchange 2013 inbox managed by a hoster. Because of the discontinued support from Microsoft, we were kind of forced to switch to Exchange 2019.

I added both accounts to Apple Mail and moved the emails (not copied) drag and drop to the other account, one folder at a time.

I do this all the time to backup our emails to a local IMAP account running on our NAS. So far I never had problems with it.

This time, when moving from Ex13 to Ex19, in some folders, the date when the email was received got switched to the date when I moved the email.

So an email with the original date 02.03.2023 has now the date 18.03.2023 (the date I moved the email). This happened only to specific folders in the account, but around 10k emails.

I already settled with it and moved on (although it is pretty unfortunate). 
Today I wanted to backup the emails again and sorted by date to only move old emails.

The sorting was all messed up which got me wondering.

In the list of emails it's sorted (old to new) like this:

- 13.03.2023
- 20.12.2022
- 01.02.2023
- 20.01.2023

So completely random order.

When I open an email it shows the wrong date 18.03.2023 (the date I moved the email) at the top right.

When I open the source of said emails, it still shows the correct date when the email was actually received. For example: `Date: Wed, 8 Feb 2023 14:56:12 +0100`

I contacted Apple, they had no clue and said I should contact the hoster, because the date is received from the Exchange server. The hoster said they have no way to sync this again.

**TLDR My question is:** 

Is there any way to sync the receive date that is in the source data of the email with the date that is used to sort and display dates in Apple Mail?

Some things to know:

- The old Exchange 2013 is gone, so I have no old copy to move the emails again
- The wrong date is already synced on the new Exchange 2019 and also displays wrong in the Outlook Web App and Outlook for Mac.
- the only straw I have left is the correct date in the source of the emails

Comment: Maybe it creates a copy of the email? Maybe you accidentally moved emails from one account's mailbox to the other's? (Which would be logical since the email.s aren't stored on the new acc)

Comment: @Thinkr I'm not 100% sure if I understand you correctly. Yes, I move emails from one account to the others, because that's what I want. They are moved, not copied

Comment: I seeㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ